# How to list parent child relationship from multidimentional array if the same child has multiple parents

Tags: php, arrays

I have mysql query which will return data from tbl_posts as an array. The array shows the parent child relationship between them as follows

```
$tree = array(
       'C1' => 'P1',//C1 is the child of P1
       'C2' => 'P1',//C2 is the child of P1
       'C3' => 'P2',//C3 is the child of P1
       'C4' => 'P3',//C4 is the child of P1
       'GC1' => 'C1',//GC1 is the child of C1
       'GC1' => 'C2',//GC1 is the child of C2
       'GC2' => 'C1',//GC2 is the child of C1
       'GC2' => 'C2',//GC2 is the child of C2
       'GC2' => 'C4',//GC2 is the child of C4

       'P1' => null,//parent post P1
       'P2' => null,//parent post  P2
       'P3' => null,//parent post P3
    );
```

Here P1, P2, P3 are parent posts and C1, C2, C3.. are child posts and GC1, GC2, GC3...are grand child according to the array which was returned by the query. 
I want to list these data according to the parent child relationship as below

```
- P1
  -- C1
    --- GC1
    --- GC2

  -- C2
    --- GC1
    --- GC2 

- P2
  -- C3

-P3
  -- C4
    --- GC2
```

I have tried this code as below

```
   function parseTree($tree, $root = null) {
   $return = array();
   foreach($tree as $child => $parent) {
       if($parent == $root) {
          $return[] = array(
            'parent' => $child,
            'child' => parseTree($tree, $child)
        );
      }
   }
  return empty($return) ? null : $return;    
}

function printTree($tree) {
if(!is_null($tree) && count($tree) > 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($tree as $node) {
        echo '<li>'.$node['parent'];
        printTree($node['child']);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}

$result = parseTree($tree);

echo "<pre>";
printTree($result);
```

And i got the result as below

```
P1
    C1
    C2
      GC1

P2
    C3

P3
    C4
      GC2
```

The grand child are are listed only once. GC1, GC2, and GC3 are child of C1, C2 and C3 but they are listed only once. How can i list the parent child relationship if the same child has multiple parents in such case? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are defining duplicate keys in your array GC1 belongs to a single parent (C2) because GC1 => C2 overwrote the previous entry.

If you change your array structure around to prevent overwriting keys, you should see the child then listed under both parents.